# Grafana-hourly-heatmap-panel marcusolsson - Not loading

Tags: grafana, heatmap

I would like to use the grafana-hourly-heatmap plugin developed by Marcus Olsson.

After building it, I tried to load it but it is not loading. The console error message indicates an issue with transpiling an ES module when loading a Grafana panel plugin.

[image: image image 3671×1812 175 KB]
I would greatly appreciate it if someone already got this error and could provide me any advice!

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the error above and other subsequent errors by just updating the libraries specified at the package.json file, especially the **Emotion library** and the **Grafana library**. Keep in mind that you must also to update the code in certain TypeScript files.